# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angularjs

I guess this means there is a circular reference somehwere but for the life of me I can't guess how to fix it.

Anyone have any ideas?

http://plnkr.co/edit/aNcBcU?p=preview

Check the debug console in Chrome (for example) and you'll see the error.
The offending line is

```
 scope.map = map;
```

scope.map is being "$watched" on the controller via

```
$scope.$watch("options.map", function (map) { ... }, true);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's because you're comparing for object for equality rather than for reference. Change your `$watch` statement to this:

```
$scope.$watch("options.map", function (map) {
    if (map === undefined) {
        alert("map has no value");
    } else {
        alert("map is defined");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you!

Just for others that may need this answer.  I guess the reason this fails is that the object being tested is an object with many deeply nest properties?

Why does testing equality on this object cause a stack size exceeded message?

Answer (score 11):

I also had this issue and found out that the objects I was comparing had circular references. (Tried `JSON.stringify()` which threw 'TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON').

When I edited my object so that it didn't have circular structure, I fixed this problem and compared objects not by reference but by properties value which was what I needed.

Answer (score 6):

The third parameter of $watch function tells how to compare the watched object. **False** to reference comparing only. **True** to recursive equality comparing,  if an object contains circular references, then over maximum stack size. For example:

```
var a = {ref:b};
var b = {ref:a};
$scope.$watch('b', function(){
  //code here will never called, because stack overflow when comparing the object b. 
}, true)
```